# web hosting publishing issue get Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I had publish my project to the web server and its get

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'.
```

May I know I'm using my target framework to 4.0 but the entity framework is 5.0 will cause this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your project's Target Framework to .Net 4.0, then re-install EF from NuGet.